# In a neural network, why is the number of hidden layer nodes frequently 2^n?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

In textbooks, I've noticed the number of nodes in the hidden layer is usually a power of 2. Is there any statistical reason for this? Or is this just an arbitrary convention?

Comment: There is no *statistical* reason.

Comment: Possibly shed some light on this:  https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-tend-to-use-powers-of-2-when-specifying-the-number-of-nodes-in-a-layer-of-a-neural-net-and-for-the-size-of-mini-batches

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a reason why a power of 2 number of layers is optimal. It seems that this is a rule of thumb or a heuristic that is broader accepted by the practitioners and coders. Some people claim that since memory hardware is managed in powers of two that might effect the computations but there exists no real proof for that at least to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I do not think that your answer is correct. This is not a "Rule of thumb". In many areas of coding, if the no. of neurons are not a power of 2, there is often an error (which is how I learned the 2power rule) Thus, it is hardcoded by the developers themselves. Your answer should be backed by some better claims, rather than "best of my knowledge". It is NOT broadly accepted. I am sure there must be a reason for it.

Comment: Thank you neel g for your down vote. However, still there is really no mathematical proof establishing why this practice is so broadly used. I am not even aware of a conjecture that claims anything. That is why I used the wording "rule of thumb" or heuristic. It is also the case that many times many rules of thumbs or "best" practices have proven wrong and abandoned throughout time, but until then their broad usage allows us to call them in such a way. Thanks